# "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" ->Google drive connection error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have an application that is connected to Google drive and transmission data to sheets.

I successfully made connections and everything works perfectly, but after a couple of hours or days (depending on the server where are user use app), my connection is broken and I got this message :

> "
> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }".

Below is code :

```
    $this->client = new Google_Client();
    $this->client->setApplicationName('BreezingForms Google Drive Spreadsheets');
    $this->client->addScope(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'));

    // testing:
    // 197794184197-bt2q9knrdu1i54vgladd97ob196k4c6s.apps.googleusercontent.com
    // dImciIWj3WNOrIcYRbu9MFeA

    if (isset($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id']) && trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id']) != '' && trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_secret']) != '') {

        $this->client->setClientId(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id']));
        $this->client->setClientSecret(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_secret']));

        $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Set custom_client_id = " . $db->quote(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_id'])) . ", custom_client_secret = " . $db->quote(trim($_POST['gdata_custom_client_secret'])) . " Where form_id = " . intval($_REQUEST['form']));
        $db->execute();

    } else {

        $form_id = -1;

        if(JRequest::getInt('ff_form',-1) > 0){

            $form_id = JRequest::getInt('ff_form',-1);

        }else if(isset($_REQUEST['form'])){

            $form_id = intval($_REQUEST['form']);
        }

        $db->setQuery("Select * From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . $db->quote($form_id));
        $client = $db->loadObject();

        if ($client) {

            $this->client->setClientId($client->custom_client_id);
            $this->client->setClientSecret($client->custom_client_secret);
        }
    }

    $this->client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
    $this->client->setPrompt('consent');
    $this->client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
    $this->client->setAccessType('offline');


}

function onPropertiesDisplay($form_id, $tabs){
    
    if(!$form_id) return '';
    
    $error = '';
    
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    
    $db->setQuery("Select `title`,`name`,`id` From #__facileforms_elements Where form = " . intval($form_id) . " And `title` Not In ('bfFakeTitle','bfFakeTitle2','bfFakeTitle3','bfFakeTitle4','bfFakeTitle5') And `type` Not In ('','UNKNOWN') Order By ordering");
    $breezingforms_fields = $db->loadObjectList();
    
    $db->setQuery("Select `enabled`, `username`, `password`, `worksheet_id`, `spreadsheet_id`, `fields`, `meta`, `debug` From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
    $gdata = $db->loadObject();
    
    if( $gdata === null ){
        $gdata = new stdClass();
        $gdata->username = '';
        $gdata->password = '';
        $gdata->enabled = 0;
        $gdata->worksheet_id = '';
        $gdata->spreadsheet_id = '';
        $gdata->fields = '';
        $gdata->meta = '';
        $gdata->debug = 0;
    }
    
    $gdata->fields = explode('/,/', $gdata->fields);
    $gdata->meta   = explode('/,/', $gdata->meta);
    
    $gdata_spreadsheets = array();
    $gdata_worksheets = array();
    $gdata_columns = array();
    $worksheets_name=array();
               $worksheets_name1=array();
               $worksheets_name2=array();

    
    //if( $gdata->enabled == 1 ){
        
        try{
        
            $spreadsheetFeed = null;
            
            $auth_url = '';
            
            $db->setQuery("Select password From #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
            $accessToken = $db->loadResult();

            if(!$accessToken){
                
                $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
                
            } else {
                
                try{
                    
                    $this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                    $token = json_decode($accessToken);
            
                    if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                        $this->client->refreshToken($token->refresh_token);
                         $tok = json_encode($this->client->getAccessToken());
                        $token = json_decode($tok);
                        $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata set password = " . $db->quote($tok) . " Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
                        $db->execute();
                    }
             
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    
                    $accessToken = null;
                    $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
                    //$error = $e->getMessage();

                }
```

After I refresh the connection, everything works again, and problems appear again.

whether know, why it happens?

Regards,

Comment: How long exactly is **but after couple other or days**  Please edit your question and include your code

Comment: Hi, after a couple of hours or days depending on the server where are user using the app, my app is use around of world, on a different server, and users are reporting that issue, and of course, I notice that problem, too. tnx :)

Comment: 1. can you verify that the refresh token is set in  $token = json_decode($accessToken); 2. Can you verify that you are always storing the newest refresh token. 3. Can you verify that your app is in production and not test in google cloud console.

Comment: Hi, yes, I can confirm all your questions, except last, my app is in status "test" in the google cloud console. Can that cause this problem?
I doubted on that! tnx :)

Comment: Have you checked if this can be the reason of the issue? [Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was been in the code -> wrong way to grab the refresh token, the correct code is:

```
 } else {
                
                try{
                    $token = json_decode($accessToken, true);
                    $this->client->setAccessToken($token);
              

                if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                         if ($this->client->getRefreshToken()) {
                 $this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
    }
               
                    }
             
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    
                    $accessToken = null;
                    $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
                 

                }
```

Now app works perfetly, nomore disconnection!

Answer (score 1):

Apps that are in test have their refresh tokens expired after seven days.

To fix it up your application into production.

[Refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Comment: Hi @Dalm To, thank you very much for your explanation! Best as always! Best regards!